# Analyzing "So am I"

Tags: phrases

> "I'm hungry."
>   "So am I."

Please reveal the reason behind saying **"So am I"**.

It seems it has an interrogative structure.
Is it wrong to say **"So I am"** ?

Comment: *So am I* (*so do I*, etc.) is a correct response to signify the person you're talking too you feel like them. You cannot use "So I am" in that case. See [here](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/fr/grammar-reference/so) or [here](http://esl.about.com/od/grammarintermediate/a/cm_sneither.htm) or [here](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/so-too-neither-either.html).

Comment: Thank you J.R for edit and also thank you Laure but I know its usage, I want to know about its structure. Why do we say "So am I" instead of "So I am"?

Comment: Perhaps it's because that's the way it is. "So am I" has been used like this since at least 1837 ([The Principle of English Grammar](http://books.google.com/books?id=flEhAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA194)).

Comment: @Dankerng Thank you, Ngram Viewer shows that first use of it goes back to 1852 :)

Comment: It can be found in Shakespeare, and I expect earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very often in a language there's no reason why we say one thing and not the other and it is merely a question of usage.

But you should be aware that both "So am I" and "So I am" exist and are not used in the same instances.

> So - Aux/V - S 
>   A: "I'm hungry"   S1 - Aux/V - specification of S1
>   B: "**So am I**"  So (an echo of specification of S1) - Aux/V - S2

The subject of the Aux/V represent a different person in the two sentences.
"So am I" being the same as saying "Me too".
To contradict A, B would say : "I'm not".

Compare with:

> So - S - Aux/V

A: "You are tired"  S1 - Aux/V - specification of S1
B: "**So I am**"  So (an echo of specification of S1) - S1 - Aux/V

In this example "you" and "I" both represent B. 
"So" would be stressed when spoken.

Other ways of responding could be :
" Yes, I am"
" You're right"
" Indeed"...

To contradict A, B would say "I'm not", same as in first example.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the two previous answers.

If you want more exact explication to that, I modify the sentence by using commas.

> **A: I am hungry.**
>
> **B: So am I.** /I am, too / Me, too.
>
> > *B literally says that "**You're hungry. I'm hungry too.**"*

Or:

> **A: I am hungry.**
>
> **B: So, am I?**
>
> > *B says that "**You're hungry. So, am I hungry?**"*. This would mean the *interrogative structure* you meant in your question.

Or:

> **A: I am hungry.**
>
> **B: So, I am.**
>
> > *B says that "You're hungry. **That's why (so),** I'm hungry too."*

That's how English works for this kind of [elliptical sentence](http://misriyantosma6.wordpress.com/2009/08/09/elliptical-sentences/). This happens with *neither am I* (or *I am not either*) too.

Comment: Good explanation.....

Answer (score 1):

In this context "so" has similar meaning to that of "also" or "likewise".

> "I'm hungry."
> "So am I."

is similar in meaning to:

> "I'm hungry."
> "I am also hungry."

However the rule for such usage is that **"So" must be followed by an auxiliary verb or do, have, or be used as main verbs.**

However, if so is followed my a noun/pronoun (like in your case of "So I am") it has a different meaning like"

> 1. **Apparently**; e.g. **So you think you've got troubles?**
> 2. used to introduce a sentence expressing resignation, amazement, or sarcasm. e.g. **so you're publishing a book!.**
>
> and many more.

But for it to mean "also" or "likewise" you must follow it with an auxiliary verb or do, have or be.